# How to enable logging for apache commons HttpClient on Android

Tags: android, apache-commons-httpclient

To enable logging for apache commons HttpClient in normal Java application I used:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.commons.httpclient", "debug");
```

But on android I don't see logs in LogCat.

Am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution (without digging into details)

**Console:**

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.httpclient.wire.header VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.httpclient.wire.content VERBOSE
```

**Code:**

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.header").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.content").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

**Test:**

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("httpclient.wire.content").log(java.util.logging.Level.CONFIG, "hola");
```

Comment: I tried this in my app, and am not seeing any log messages delivered from the HttpClient.  Does this work using the HttpClient that is in the current SDK?  That is, org.apache.http, vs org.apache.commons.http.

I do see the test log message ("hola" in your example), but nothing from the HttpClient calls.

Comment: with recent SDKs you need to use prefix used in the first response, "org.apache.http" instead of "httpclient", at least this worked for me on a 2.1 Device.

Comment: @alex2k8 - Why do you need to set the adb shell properties?

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's a way to see MORE detail than what you get with enabling DEBUG mode on the wire? Like low level TCP information?

Answer (score 65):

Ignore my earlier comment.  I found the solution on the org.apache.http logging page.  Your original answer was referring to [httpclient-3.x logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html), and the working code for recent versions comes from [http-components logging](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/logging.html)

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.httpclient.wire", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http", "debug");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.headers", "debug");
```

and properties:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE
```

The difference is in the logging tag names.

Comment: Have you been able to get context logging to work? I tried extending your solution with similar lines for the org.apache.http.impl.client logger, but I'm not seeing anything from classes in that package or subpackage. I do get the wire and header logging however.

Comment: @joe - Why do you need to set the adb shell properties?

Comment: Also, to see the headers, only this line was needed: `java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);`. I didn't need to set any java system property.

Comment: The lines were just showing what *could* be set if you want parts of the logging.  If you only need one of the log tags, then you only need to set that one.  The setprop is used for making sure that the "httpclient.wire.header" tag gets logged. If you wanted to change the log behavior (or disable the log entirely), you could use that command to change the level at which logcat will show those logs.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we hard-code this into the application? Surely the whole point of setting this outside the app is so the logging is configurable! Please would you explain what you are doing in more detail or better yet, provide an example on github? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The devil is in the details. I'm running the 2.3.3 emulator and got it working with:

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.wire").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.headers").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
```

and in the adb shell

```
# setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.wire VERBOSE
# setprop log.tag.org.apache.http.headers VERBOSE
```

Thus it seems the log specifiers are different.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(yourFullClassName).setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.All);
```

and

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.correspondingTag VERBOSE
```

Android use this function to get correspondingTag from class full name:

```
public static String loggerNameToTag(String loggerName)
  {
    if (loggerName == null) {
      return "null";
    }

    int length = loggerName.length();
    if (length <= 23) {
      return loggerName;
    }

    int lastPeriod = loggerName.lastIndexOf(".");
    return length - (lastPeriod + 1) <= 23 ? loggerName.substring(lastPeriod + 1) : loggerName.substring(loggerName.length() - 23);
  }
```

so  for example，I want to enable logging for “org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector” class，do such things below:

```
String clzName = "org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector";
String newClzName = loggerNameToTag(clzName);
System.out.println("className:" + clzName + " tagName is " + newClzName);    //get tagName from class full name,and then it will be used in setprop
Logger jdkLogger = Logger.getLogger(clzName);
jdkLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
if (jdkLogger.isLoggable(Level.FINE))
{
        jdkLogger.log(Level.FINE, "jdk log msg");    
        jdkLogger.log(Level.Fine,"tagName is")
}
```

And then in adb shell

```
setprop log.tag.DefaultRequestDirector VERBOSE
```

Answer (score 0):

For Apache Http Components version 5.x, you need to use `slf4j` logging Facade e.g. `JUL` (Jakarta Common Logging) to bind a logging backend at compile time.

```
implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:2.0.0-alpha7'
```

Retrieve the `root` logger via

```
final Logger rootLogger = java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("");
```

or

```
final Logger rootLogger = java.util.logging.LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("")
```

Set the logging level to proper level, otherwise messages are discarded

```
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

Implement your own `java.util.logging.Handler` for receiving messages

```
public static class LogHandler extends Handler {

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(LogRecord record) {
        final Level level = record.getLevel();
        if (level == Level.INFO) {
            Log.i(record.getLoggerName(), record.getMessage());
        } else if (level == Level.WARNING) {
            Log.w(record.getLoggerName(), record.getMessage());
        } else if (level == Level.SEVERE) {
            Log.e(record.getLoggerName(), record.getMessage());
        } else if (level == Level.FINE) {
            Log.d(record.getLoggerName(), record.getMessage());
        } else {
            Log.v(record.getLoggerName(), record.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Set the handler

```
final LogHandler logHandler = new LogHandler();
rootLogger.addHandler(logHandler);
```

And for goodies a `setLevel` function for modules. A container is required to keep strong reference to uninitialized external loggers, otherwise garbage collector will deallocate and `level` parameter will be set to default.

```
private static HashMap<String, Logger> sLoggerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Class to hold `modules`

```
public static class Module {
    final String mModule;

    public static final Module APACHE_HTTP = new Module("org.apache.hc.client5.http");
    public static final Module APACHE_HTTP_WIRE = new Module("org.apache.hc.client5.http.wire");
    public static final Module APACHE_HTTP_HEADERS = new Module("org.apache.hc.client5.http.headers");

    Module(final String module) {
        mModule = module;
    }
}
```

With function

```
public static void setLogging(final Module module, final Level level) {
    Logger logger = sLoggerMap.get(module.mModule);
    if (logger == null) {
        logger = Logger.getLogger(module.mModule);
        sLoggerMap.put(module.mModule, logger);
    }
    logger.setLevel(level);
}
```

And use it like so (I'm encapsulating everything inside `Logging` class)

```
Logging.setLogging(Logging.Module.APACHE_HTTP_WIRE, Level.FINE);
```

It has its own drawbacks when requests are async. Switching log level will affect all the in progress request.

For release build, add following to `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-keep class org.apache.hc.client5.http.** {
    <fields>;
    <methods>;
}
```