# MultipartEntity not creating good request

Tags: android, http-post, multipartentity

I needed to send some XML to a webservices and I was able to do it with a normal StringEntity because it was just text but now I need to attach an image to it as well. I tried doing it with a MultipartEntity but I couldn't get it working with just the XML.

// Working

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost doc = new HttpPost("http://mywebservices.com");

HttpEntity entity = new StringEntity(writer.toString());
httppost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

// not working

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost doc = new HttpPost("http://mywebservices.com");

// no difference when removing the BROWSER_COMPATIBLE   
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE); 
entity.addPart("xml", new StringBody(writer.toString()));
httppost.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
```

And is there a way I could see the MIME that is being send?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply forgot:

```
httppost.setEntity(entity);
```

By the way, it's probably good form to set the Content-Type of your parts, e.g.:

```
entity.addPart("xml", new StringBody(writer.toString(),"application/xml",Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

As far as seeing what's being sent, see http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html (especially "wire logging") for the HttpClient logging features, and
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android) for how to get it working on Android.

Comment: oh I see I forgot to copy the `httppost.setEntity(entity);`, it was in my code but didn't work :(

Comment: The webservices is unable to read the request and gives me an error back. So the `MultipartEntity` generates another post than the normal `HttpEntity` but I'm unable to see the post.

Comment: Well, the post with the multipart entity will definitely be different from the post with an xml entity.  Do you know that the web service accepts multipart?  To see the post, use the wire logging from this answer, or see my other answer.

Comment: I'm so stupid... I commented the `httppost.setEntity(entity);` line. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to see what's being sent is to set up your own "server" to receive the request.  You can do this on a Unix-like system with netcat.  The command-line

```
nc -l 1234
```

starts a server listening on port 1234, and will echo whatever is received.

If that "server" is on a machine 10.1.2.3, you can just use a `new HttpPost("http://10.1.2.3:1234")` to send the message there.

Comment: A little addition, if you want to do this on Windows you can download NetCat here http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139 and you should run it like this.
`C:\path\to\nc.exe -l -p 1234`

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem but I'm sending the multipart with user/pass to a acegi security system, it works with this:

```
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

But not with this:

```
try {   
    for (NameValuePair param : params) {
        multientity.addPart(param.getName(), new StringBody(param.getValue(),      Charset.forName(encoding))));
    }
    request.setEntity(multientity);
}
```

Comment: You imply that the answer to the question is the first block of code?