# how to track http packets on android in java

Tags: java, android

I wish to track all http packets going out and comming in to the device 
from a service is that possible ?

Thanks
Vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apache HttpClient you can turn on logging, see "[How to enable logging for apache commons HttpClient on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android)".  The options for logging are very flexible.

But Google's energy is going into HttpURLConnection (see "[Android Developer's Blog: Android's HTTP Clients](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html)"), perhaps somebody else can suggestion good ways to turn on logging there.  There's one idea at "[HTTP Get Using Android HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654876/http-get-using-android-httpurlconnection)" though that particular example would disrupt your service.

Then there's always [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/).