# How can I turn on Logging in android's DefaultRedirectHandler?

Tags: android

I would like to turn on logging for android's DefaultRedirectHandler.
I read the code, it uses org.apache.commons.logg`enter code here`ing.LogFactory to set/check the log level.

Problem is when I try to get a reference to org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory, that class is not visible to my application.

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
public class DefaultRedirectHandler implements RedirectHandler {
//... omitted
private final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

String location = locationHeader.getValue();
if (this.log.isDebugEnabled()) {
    this.log.debug("Redirect requested to location '" + location + "'");
}
//... omitted
```

I have followed the steps here:
[How to enable logging for apache commons HttpClient on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android)

I have tried putting this in my apk:
                 java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.impl.client").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.impl.conn").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http.client").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.FINEST);

```
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");

    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.client", "debug");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.client", "debug");
    System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.impl.conn", "debug");
```

But that does not help me. 
I am testing on a Gingerbread device.

Thank you for any help.