# Adding multiple custom http request headers mystery

Tags: java, https, http-headers, httpclient

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("https://192.168.1.140:8732/...);
```

I wonder why I can only send successfully for custom headers : UserName and AuthToken if I do the following:

```
    request.setHeader("User-Agent", "android_client");
    request.setHeader("Host", "192.168.1.140:8732");
    request.addHeader("UserName", mUserName);
    request.addHeader("AuthToken", mAuthorizationToken);
```

Why is that this code NOT sending the UserName but AuthToken only? When the two bottom lines are reversed.

```
    request.setHeader("User-Agent", "android_client");
    request.setHeader("Host", "192.168.1.140:8732");
    request.addHeader("AuthToken", mAuthorizationToken);
    request.addHeader("UserName", mUserName);
```

Why is this code failing with 400 error code, invalid hostname when I don't specific the host

```
//  request.setHeader("User-Agent", "android_client");
//  request.setHeader("Host", "192.168.1.140:8732");
    request.addHeader("UserName", mUserName);
    request.addHeader("AuthToken", mAuthorizationToken);
```

If I don't need to send the UserName and AuthToken, I don't really need to set the Host and it works just fine with the code commented out like following

```
//  request.setHeader("User-Agent", "android_client");
//  request.setHeader("Host", "192.168.1.140:8732");
```

Though I don't think that it is related, I want to disclose that I am using self-signed certificate for these http call from android following this [blog](http://blog.antoine.li/2010/10/22/android-trusting-ssl-certificates/). Looking forward to the divine revelation for my poor http soul ...

Comment: How do you know what is actually being sent? Did you examine the data stream with Fiddler?  It will proxy HTTPS with a little configuration.

Comment: I also write the server side code in WCF C#. So I am aware of what is being sent. Using fiddler adding the two custom headers went through. It is only from those android client code, that is having issue.

Comment: @Win Myo Htet: You can see what HTTP packets get sent access the wire by activating wire / context logging on the client side. You'll see whether or not all request headers are included in the request message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a fluke. I couldn't reproduce it anymore. I have been working with the working solution and left it for a while working on different project. I come back and take a look with wire /context logging at [oleg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/335638/oleg) suggestion with the help of [How to enable logging for apache commons HttpClient on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android) I couldn't reproduce the problem anymore. The power of the logging has scared the problem away. Will update if the problem occurs again and if I find out the cause.