# Chrome Tab Breaks with RESULT_CODE_KILLED_BAD_MESSAGE when service worker tries to cache requests which contain headers with utf-8 characters

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker

I stumbled upon this issue during development and it took me quite some hours to figure out. It seems that if you have a `service worker` and your `service worker` tries to cache a request which contains a header with the `ü` character in `Chrome` browser tab will break entirely with **RESULT_CODE_KILLED_BAD_MESSAGE** leaving you without any reasonable error message for it. Or at least pointing you in the right direction for finding the fix.
[image]

I tested the same thing in `Safari` / `Firefox` and it seems this browsers ignore this character and are not affected by the issue. While adding the character `ü` in a header is forbidden by the spec as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779860/using-json-string-in-the-http-header) I would expect `Chrome` to give a better error and not just die.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious fix is to encode with base 64 your headers to ensure there are not no weird characters which are not allowed. The fix can be found also on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779860/using-json-string-in-the-http-header) but the connection is hard to make while googling for results.

```
btoa(myStringWithNotAllowedCharacters)
```