# Is it possible to store an object in HttpHeaders in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

Forgive my ignorance - a jr developer here. I'm trying to make a **PUT** call to a client API. In the documentation it shows the request headers have an object in them. I thought headers could only have a *String* value. How can I add an object to my HttpHeaders object?

*Request Model from API Documentation*

```
requestHeader {
  "headerA": "valueA",
  "headerB": {
    "headerB1": "valueB1",
    "headerB2": "valueB2"
  },
  "headerC": "valueC"
}

requestBody { 
  "object": { 
              "variable1": 12345, 
              "variable2": 54321 
  }, 
  "sameNums": false }
```

I'm using HttpHeaders from package org.springframework.http - the set() and add() methods take Strings as parameters. How can I add an object as a header value?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779860/using-json-string-in-the-http-header

Comment: From description of the task taken literally it seems you have to convert your object to its json representation and after insert it in the request header, the link suggested by @Pavel seems me very helpful.

Comment: @Pavel & dariosicily thank you! This was helpful and insightful