# Android, why HttpPost method returns two different results in Android v2.3 and Android v4.0.3?

Tags: android, proxy, http-post

I have created a sample code to compare output of HttpPost method in two different Android OSs, v2.3 and v4.0. I have a sim-card that I'm using 3G service of an operator. Therefore, I'm connecting to Internet through 3G service. Proxy server address and port is set automatically by mobile operator and is same for both of them.

My code is like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Log.i(TAG, "inside onCreate()...");


        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Internet connection found.");
            new MyAsyncTask().execute();
        } else
            Log.i(TAG, "Internet connection not found.");
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute()...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            boolean status = false;

            String xml = postData();    
            if(xml != null)
                status = true;

            return status;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (result) 
                Log.i(TAG, "Process finished successfully...");
        }
    }

    private String postData() {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://demo.excelforce.com.my/mobiletraderjssb/dopwd.aspx?");

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("u", Uri.encode("test01")));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p", Encryption.encrypt("112233")));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("v", "1.1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("t", "0"));

        try {
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            Log.i("Requestd Connection", httppost.getURI().toString());


            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.i("Server Response: ", responseBody);

            if (response.containsHeader("Set-Cookie")) {
                String sessionId = extractSessionId(response.getHeaders("Set-Cookie")[0].getValue());
//              PropertyManager.setSessionID(sessionId);
                Log.i("Session Id:", sessionId);
            } else
                Log.e("ERROR", "Response doesn't have Set-Cookie in header");

                return responseBody;

        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException usee) {
            usee.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClientProtocolException cpe) {
            cpe.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String extractSessionId(String str) {
        String session = null;
        if (str!=null)
            session = str.substring(0, str.indexOf(";"));
        return session;
    }
}
```

When I run this application on Android v2.3 device (Samsung Galaxy S), my output is like this in logcat:

```
07-09 18:21:11.031: I/MainActivity(1277): inside onCreate()...
07-09 18:21:11.035: I/MainActivity(1277): Internet connection found.
07-09 18:21:11.035: I/MainActivity(1277): onPreExecute()...
07-09 18:21:11.718: I/Requestd Connection(1277): http://demo.excelforce.com.my/mobiletraderjssb/dopwd.aspx?
07-09 18:21:13.941: I/Server Response:(1277): <TD ID="LGFLAG">S</TD><TD ID="LGMSG"></TD><TD ID="CLNT_0">CLNTXXX,EF TEST,C,001,</TD>
07-09 18:21:13.941: I/Session Id:(1277): ASPNETSESSIONID=jjodj3m22notn1m50oxs0u55
07-09 18:21:13.941: I/MainActivity(1277): Process finished successfully...
```

While, when I run the application on Android V4.0.3 (Samsung Galaxy 2 or HTC Xperia), output is like this in logcat:

```
07-09 18:08:45.085: I/MainActivity(19358): inside onCreate()...
07-09 18:08:45.090: I/MainActivity(19358): Internet connection found.
07-09 18:08:45.090: I/MainActivity(19358): onPreExecute()...
07-09 18:08:45.155: I/Requestd Connection(19358): http://demo.excelforce.com.my/mobiletraderjssb/dopwd.aspx?
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358):     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <head>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <title></title>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): </head>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <body>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <table>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <tr>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <td id="LGFLAG">S</td>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <td id="LGMSG"></td>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): <td id="CLNT_0">CLNTXXX,EF TEST,C,001,</td>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): </tr>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): </table>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): </body>
07-09 18:08:46.235: I/Server Response:(19358): </html>
07-09 18:08:46.235: E/ERROR(19358): Response doesn't have Set-Cookie in header
07-09 18:08:46.440: I/MainActivity(19358): Process finished successfully...
```

As you can see my XML data is wrapped by HTML Code. This HTML code comes from where? 
Someone said maybe it is because of Proxy server which is set automatically by mobile operator. Is it correct? I think it shouldn't be correct because if proxy server manipulate my code or inject something to my code in v4.0.3 why I don't have same response with Android v2.0 and v3.0? Is it because of bug inside Android v4.0?!!!

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I think there is a difference in request in Android 2.x and 4.x which is treated by server differently.

Comment: I agree with 'pawelzieba' ... what are the headers you're submitting?  The server is receiving something which is different, obviously, and the headers would be a good place to check (simply iterate through them as its a collection).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like missing accept contet-type for request.

Try to add something like:

```
httppost.setHeader("Accept","application/xml");
```

If not then set up Apache HttpClient logging on:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3303131/538169
and look for differences in requests.

Comment: Thanks dear pawelzieba, I think its not because of this header setting. Because, when i manually clear proxy server ip and port from mobile-phone, application works fine without problem. Just when I'm using Internet through proxy server and OS is v4.0, my XML data is wrapping with HTML code. I have no idea why proxy server wrap my data in Android v4.0 while it doesn't wrap it on Android v2.0 or v3.0!!! It is making me crazy!!!!!

Comment: I suggest to turn HttpClient loggin on and look where is the difference in request. I'm almost sure that server interpretes requests from ICS and older systems differently. Probably ICS implementation has set or unset some headers by default which were on older API.