# Issue on POSTING data by using "NameValuePair"

Tags: java, http-post, httpclient

I wrote in java method that responsable to send `POST` like `ajax`

```
public String getWebInfo() {

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
    String out = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("send started");
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password");


         httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                    cred);

         HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://page/php/data.ajax.php");

        List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "1"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "2"));

        UrlEncodedFormEntity entityU = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps);
        entityU.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
        //entityU.setContentType("application/json");
        httpost.setEntity(entityU);



        System.out.println("send about to do post");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
        System.out.println("send post done");
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            System.out.println("response.getStatusLine: " + response.getStatusLine());
            InputStream is = entity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("Response: " +  line);
                out = line;
            }
            is.close();

        } else {
            System.out.println("Response: response is null");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }

    if (httpclient != null) {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return out;     
}
```

The output is empty:

```
send started
send about to do post
send post done
response.getStatusLine: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Response: []
```

**Server side**

from my logs on `msqLogFile("page/post",Array('post' => urldecode(implode(", ", $_POST))));`

I get only data without key:

```
"2013-05-02 04:21:09","1,2"
```

it should be json data:

from  `tail -f /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_request_log`

```
 82.80.25.130 TLSv1 AES128-SHA "POST /page/php/data.ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 484
 82.80.25.130 TLSv1 AES128-SHA "POST /page/php/data.ajax.php HTTP/1.1" 3
```

When I uncomment `entityU.setContentType("application/json");`, I get no data at all.

From javascript all works fine:

```
var json = JSON.stringify({action: 1,name: 2});
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/page/php/data.ajax.php",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{data:json},
            success:function(data){
```

And here I get response:

```
"2013-05-02 04:21:09","{"action":1,"name":2}"
```

Where is my problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you used Wireshark to see what actually goes over the line? I suspect your nvp objects not being serialized correctly.

Comment: I tried to send json data only but by this way POST is empty

Answer (score 0):

I found workaround but suppose someone will find better response:

```
public String getWebInfo() {

DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
String out = null;

try {
    System.out.println("send started");
    httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    Credentials cred = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password");


     httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT, AuthScope.ANY_REALM),
                cred);

     HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("https://page/php/data.ajax.php");

     JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
     jsonObj.put("action", 1);
     jsonObj.put("name", 2);


    List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
    nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObj.toString()));


    UrlEncodedFormEntity entityU = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps);
    entityU.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
    //entityU.setContentType("application/json");
    httpost.setEntity(entityU);



    System.out.println("send about to do post");
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpost);
    System.out.println("send post done");
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        System.out.println("response.getStatusLine: " + response.getStatusLine());
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Response: " +  line);
            out = line;
        }
        is.close();

    } else {
        System.out.println("Response: response is null");
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.getStackTrace();
}

if (httpclient != null) {
    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}

return out;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

good that u found it. I read thru post and looked at how you are testing and have a suggestion.

If you are using alot of http, then you would get good results in dev from being able to CURL all your expressions in order to see that your workflow across the net is OK. If you need to , your unit testing can include Bash scripts that just send a large sequence of http traffic...

In java you need to find a way to toggle the http logs so that your normal logger can write HEADER/ WIRE statements that look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526044/httpput-get-full-request-string/15526296#15526296) --see accept ans--

You will clearly see all the header TO and FRM the server, all the body info on the WIRE to/frm the server that appears with directionals "<<" or ">>" in your normal logger.

Its tricky to figure out how to do , but worth the reading IMO when you get figure out.

[read](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html)