# Android-- HttpClient runtime exception while executing a HttpGet request

Tags: android, httpclient

I was building an enquiry to google's direction service, but the execute method crashed halfway, Here's the code

```
Uri.Builder b = Uri.parse("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json").buildUpon();

                b.appendQueryParameter("origin", "The University of Hong KOng");
                b.appendQueryParameter("destination", "Lee Hysan Hall");
                b.appendQueryParameter("sensor", "false");
                b.appendQueryParameter("language", "en_US");

                String finalstr = b.build().toString();

                URI googledirectionservice = new URI(finalstr); 

                HttpGet mRequest = new HttpGet(googledirectionservice);
                HttpClient mClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                response = mClient.execute(mRequest);
```

The url constructed is fine when I access it from my browser, but it wouldn't work accessed from the HttpClient.You can double check with

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=The%20University%20of%20Hong%20KOng&destination=Lee%20Hysan%20Hall&sensor=false&language=en_US
```

What would be the reason? Besides, how can I make the debugging information more informative? The current ones in logcat showed nothing more than

```
threadid=... thread exiting with uncaught exception
```

Comment: What exception do you see?

Comment: You could also get the statusCode from the response. That could help too

Comment: have you added INTERNET_PERMISSION to your manifest? Is that snipped of code running in the UI Thread?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I am not sure, it's an uncaught exception. There's nothing else I know from the logcat.

Comment: @BigT, the thing is, it crashed in the middle of execute, so I couldn't get even response object

Comment: @blackbelt, I have that one in my manifest

Comment: @blackbelt, the code runs in my service. can that be the problem?

Comment: of course. service runs in the UI Thread. You need an AsyncTask or a Thread subclass

Comment: Is all the code you posted in a try-catch block?

In addition, it is always recommended to move network operation off the UI thread, for example, using AsyncTask.

(Don't you have any "Caused by: ..." in the logcat? It's unusual).

Comment: @blackbelt, yeah.. that's the Devil. I have moved the above code in another thread and it worked! huge thanks!

Comment: @David, nice suggestion, I will do the try-catch block in future. I have moved the code off UI thread and it worked like a charm. great thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try turning on logging in your client. instructions sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915414/disable-httpclient-logging) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android)

Access to the WIRE logs and to the HEADER logs is a must in developing networked apps. So, depending on the client you are using for your http implementation, you should google until you know how to expose the appropriate logs. If you have the logs for WIRE and for HEADERS, answers to questions like you post will be pretty much self-evident in the log details.

In my case, i just keep available an extra jar file built with my http implementation with the logs activated and when i need to debug the network, i just rebuild my app with that jar. It all depends on which http lib you have chosen.

list of libs:

[loopj](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

[volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)

Comment: great pointers, I will save it in case it's useful in the future. For now, moving code off the UI thread fixed everything. Anyway, thanks all the same!