# Enable logging in httpclientandroidlib

Tags: android, html

I am using [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/) in my android application and having trouble logging debug logs from this library.

I had tried the following as per the instruction on the project page:

```
httpClient.log.enableDebug(true);
```

I have also tried the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246792/how-to-enable-logging-for-apache-commons-httpclient-on-android).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the way to enable logging in [httpclientandroidlib](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/). Following APIs can enable different level of logging (mainly to html messages/headers that are being sent):

```
ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.INSTANCE.wirelog.enableDebug(true);
ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.INSTANCE.headerlog.enableDebug(true);
ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.INSTANCE.log.enableDebug(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

in any of the org.apache classes with statement

```
 Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.DEBUG);
```

like **./impl/conn/WireHC4.java**

just hi-lite the code for the the suggestion:

"Before you make any calls to a logging method you should check to see if your tag should be logged. You can change the default level by setting a system property: 'setprop log.tag. ' Where level is either VERBOSE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, ASSERT, or SUPPRESS. SUPPRESS will turn off all logging for your tag. You can also create a local.prop file that with the following in it: 'log.tag.=' and place that in /data/local.prop."

That said, all that u need to do to get WIRE & HEADERS at VERBOSE is to include the following in your MainActivity.onCreate()

```
//TEST ONLY
System.setProperty("log.tag.Headers", "VERBOSE");
System.setProperty("log.tag.Wire", "VERBOSE");
```

OR , without alter code, use the adb shell to set props above...

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.Wire VERBOSE
```